# 500 (Internal Server Error) when retrieving one document from MongoDB without using _id

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack (my first project) and I don't find the solution to successfully request a single element from MongoDB. The page that I am describing is opened when a user wants to edit an item out of a given list on the main page. My aim is, that the information of the clicked item (from the main page) is displayed on the edit-page.

These are the relevant lines from the server.js:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/item_list", {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});

<...>

const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({id: {type: Number, required: true},
  text: {type: String, required: true}
  }); 
  
<...>
//get single item from db
app.get('/item/:id', async (request, response) => {
  try{
  var result = await Item.findById( {id: request.params.id} ).exec();
  response.send(result);
}catch(error){
  response.status(500).send(error);
}});
```

In the service module, I am using the following function to call the API:

```
getItem(id: number): Observable<Item> {
    const url = '/item/'+id;
    return this.http
      .get<Item>(url)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<Item>(`getItem id=${id}`)));
  }
```

In the typescript file of the "output"-module I am using the following function:

```
@Input() item: Item;

getItem(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
    this.itemService.getItem(id)
    .subscribe(item => this.item = item);
  }
```

The route contains the (unique) id of the item, that I assigned to it - it is the id with which my request queries the database.
Here the code snippet of the link from the main page that leads to the Edit-page:

```
<a routerLink="/edit-item/ {{item.id}}">Edit</a>
```

However, I am receiving an Internal Server Error. I believe, that the problem is the method ".findById({...})" in the server.js. I have other requests that are working (e.g. retrieving the whole item list), so the database connection is working fine. Any hints are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findById` is a method on the model to find a document by its _id.

You can look into documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById).

Replace the line as follows to make it work

```
  var result = await Item.findById( {_id: request.params.id} ).exec();
```

If you need to find by a different custom Id and want to query a single document then use `findOne` as documented [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Comment: In my case the findOne()-option was what I needed + I had to remove the colons in the link of the function in the service. Thanks a lot, you saved my day!